# Reshape wide data to long format

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape, melt

I am facing trouble reshaping my wide data into a long format using `reshape` `melt`.But I couldn't find a solution best suited to my need. Sorry if I am duplicating this question. My monthly data (CSV file)of a single variable is in the following format;

```
Date        level1  level2  level3  level4 ..... level100
1/1/2003    191.3    191.4  191.4   191.4
1/2/2003    184.3    184.3  184.3   184.3
1/3/2003    176.5    176.5  176.5   176.5
1/4/2003    175.5    175.5  175.5   175.5
..
..
1/12/2003
```

I am trying to reshape in this format

```
Date        Level   value
1/1/2003    1       191.3
1/1/2003    2       191.4
..      ..      ..
1/1/2003    100     #value
1/2/2003    1       #value
1/2/2003    2       #value
..
1/2/2003    100     #value
```

and so on...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` -

```
result <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, 
                    cols = -Date, 
                    names_to = 'Level',
                    names_pattern = 'level(\\d+)'
                    )

result

#    Date     Level value
#   <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
# 1 1/1/2003 1      191.
# 2 1/1/2003 2      191.
# 3 1/1/2003 3      191.
# 4 1/1/2003 4      191.
# 5 1/2/2003 1      184.
# 6 1/2/2003 2      184.
# 7 1/2/2003 3      184.
# 8 1/2/2003 4      184.
# 9 1/3/2003 1      176.
#10 1/3/2003 2      176.
#11 1/3/2003 3      176.
#12 1/3/2003 4      176.
#13 1/4/2003 1      176.
#14 1/4/2003 2      176.
#15 1/4/2003 3      176.
#16 1/4/2003 4      176.
```

To write the output to csv use `write.csv` -

```
write.csv(result, 'result.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: how can I write this output in another csv file?

Comment: You can use `write.csv` to write the file. See updated answer.

Comment: Wow! that is what I wanted. I also added extra `values_to='variable_name'` to get my desired variable name in the output.

Comment: I am still eager to know solution using `melt`

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution using `melt` after a bit of search. Though, couldn't completely done using melt. `order` and `gsub` were used alongside to get the exact output. Maybe it will be useful to somebody. Please feel free to edit if any improvement needed.

```
Date=as.Date(d$Date,format='%d%m%Y')
df_melt <- melt(d, id.vars = c("Date"), 
                variable.name = "Level", 
                value.name = "name_of_interest", 
                measure.vars = names(d[,2:101]))
b<- df_melt[order(as.Date(df_melt$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),] # to get the date in order
b$Level<-gsub("level","",as.numeric(b$Level)) # to remove the string "level"
write.csv(b,"result.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```